# WooCommerce phone number field validation not working if the field contains only one "0" character

Tags: php, regex, validation, woocommerce, preg-match

I wrote a regular expression that validates the phone number in WooCommerce. It works in all cases, unless the field contains a single "0" character.

What could be the error?

That's the code:

```php
$post_value = $_POST['billing_phone'];   
if ( $post_value && ! preg_match( '/^(\+49)[0-9]{9,}$/', $post_value ) ) {      
    //error                                         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not match `0` or `+490`. So the problem is probably that something in that if statement is different when the POST param `'billing_phone'` is 0. In PHP `if (int)` is true for any int other than 0 and false for 0, perhaps that is the problem?

So you could solve that by something like this:

```
if ( ($post_value || $post_value == 0) && ! preg_match( '/^(\+49)[0-9]{9,}$/', $post_value ) ) {
```

(Disclaimer: I am generally not very familiar with PHP.)

Answer (score 0):

You could write the pattern using an alternation matching only a single zero.

If you don't need the separate capture group for the `+49` for after processing you can omit it.

```
^(?:\+49\d{9,}|0)$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uolHYg/1).